# Recursive function in solidity(array parameter)

Tags: solidity, python, recursive

I'm trying to implement a recursive function with solidity as we did in Python or JavaScript. Parameters must be an array. and implement functions like this Python function. Can you help me?

```
def myfunc(array):
if len(array) <= 1:
    return array
left = []
right =[]
n=array[len(array)//2]
#some code...
return myfunc(left)+[n]+myfunc(right)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/76633/recursive-function-in-solidity) is an answer from 3 years ago. You can upvote the original post.

> It is possible to use recursive functions in Solidity. The following
> is a simple recursive function in solidity
>
> pragma solidity ^0.5.12;
>
> contract Test {
> uint x;
> function set(uint y) public {
> x = y;
> }
>
> ```
> function factorial(uint y) internal pure returns(uint){
>     if (y == 1){
>         return y;
>     } else {
>         return y * factorial(y-1);
>     }
> }
>
> function get() public view returns(uint){
>     return factorial(x);
> } }
> ```
>
> But please be aware that you should know what you are doing since
> recursive functions can end up costing huge gas and cause the
> transaction to revert atomically.